# Navigation Stack transform base_link to /map error

Tags: ros, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to run a turtlebot 2 with and RPLidar. I launch the RPLidar node and the turtlebot bring up followed by the move_base from the tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup).

Currently I am running into this error: [ WARN] [1500061606.588011960]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.101218 timeout was 0.1.

I also don't think my tf_tree looks correct: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-2f_ZBhV2PKVkhCZW1vaVY3em8/view?usp=sharing

Even after reading the tf wiki page, I am having trouble understanding how to configure it and integrate tf into my project. There is no "map" transformation, and there are two separate trees...

Any help would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266418/navigation-stack-transform-base_link-to-/map-error/) by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2017-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-07-16**:
Whatever mobile_base_nodelet_manager is, looks like you configure it to use base_footprint as frame while you should have used base_link. An alternative solution would be to provide a static transform from base_link to base_footprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems you are not running AMCL. This node localizes the robot in a previously built map, and provide the map->odom transform, which is missing in your tree.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1